# ADO CursorType adOpenForwardOnly Why Errors happen

Tags: cursor, ado

ADO CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly

Why does the method .MoveFirst not error but .MovePrevious throws exception

Are not both calls moving backward?

Comment: Not if you are already at the first record, they are not.

Comment: in pseudo code asdf asdf adsf

Comment: In pseudo:  cursortype = forward

Comment: In pseudo:
    RS.Cursor = Forward
    Open RS
    Loop till end of RS 'so that .EOF = True

    .MoveFirst '  this is ok
    .MovePrevious 'throws and error

'Queston:  is the cursor service not backing up on
''both .MoveFirst and .MovePrevious